# Sending Text to a non-active window using PostMessage can't send shift though

Tags: c++, windows

Ok, so I created a really simple SendText Function

```
void SendText(string str)
{
    for (std::string::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {           
        PostMessage(h, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan(*it), 0);
    }
return;
}
```

The problem is pretty apparent, but the workaround is not. If send the string

Hello World!

The outputted text is "hello world1"...

However, the way this app handles my messages, I'm unable to simply check if shift needs to be held and send VK_SHIFT messages. Basically, the app doesn't handle KEYDOWN and KEYUP messages, it simply treats them as keypressed events.

So it turns into  Shift Pressed / Released ..... Key Pressed / Released ... Shift Pressed / Released.

The GOAL:

To somehow use a single postmessage to send the correct shifted or unshifted character to the app. Or possibly maybe other ideas as to why the keydown/keyups are just translated to keypressed. And it must be able to be handled in the background (ala no send input)

Comment: Don't do this. Use SendInput instead. Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: SendInput can't be used to a background process sadly :( Edited my final lines to show I meant to say background process as well.

Comment: You should tag this question with something about the OS or ToolKit etc. involved: it's not about portable C++.

Comment: @TonyD - are you aware of any differences between different versions of Windows (or toolkits) when simulating input?

Comment: @enhzflep: Literally every way of providing input has nothing to do with standard C++. So, yes.

Comment: @enhzflep: there are certainly differences between windowing environments (e.g. MS Windows vs. XWindows); that was what all I was getting at - that the graphics environment ought to be stated in the question tags (as it now is). I'm not aware of differences between MS Windows versions.

Comment: PostMessage(h, `WM_CHAR`

Comment: @Blacktempel tried, no luck that actually converts things in a MUCH wierder way lol.

Comment: @Casper7526 That seems to be strange, I have done this before, I could not get shift to work either, and used a check if the letter is uppercase or a special character and sent it with `WM_CHAR`, which works pretty good. What does the string `HeLL0#_?This*is=A:TestRun` output if you send it with `WM_CHAR` ?

Comment: @Blacktempel http://i.gyazo.com/5c7f98a670279ff2688e5515c0f65a4c.png

Comment: @Casper7526 This is taken out of one of my classes from my working MFC application. [Try this code.](http://pastebin.com/GLbwhxTs) Taken from your picture, I assume that this project is *probably* not Unicode. You might run into issues with that.

Comment: @Blacktempel That got it working 99.9% right I guess haha, now the only problem is what I assume to be the app handling the messages horribly...

Sending Text AaAaAa results in AAAaaa being printed lol.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, your project is likely not Unicode.

Taken this out of one of my projects, sending keys should now work.

[Permalink](http://pastebin.com/GLbwhxTs)

Please take note, that I have encountered issues with sending strings - whole text messages - as the window may not (be able to) handle them as fast as you send them. A small delay between the keys can fix this issue. In my project I have a thread for sending texts, using a [std::queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) (with mutex...) to work through all texts. Therefore a short call to [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wouldn't be too wrong, in case you have a thread for this.

You can try different delays, also always depending on your computer. Older operating systems or older computers may be slower and need a higher delay. You could either add checks for the OS/specs, or an option to user-define the delay between the characters of your text.

*If anyone has a direct solution to send <kbd>Shift</kbd> to a background window, feel free to leave a comment and I will edit my answer.*